# How to stop textbox data being lost when I update my KendoGrid

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid that uses an editor template with a text input which is populated by javascript.  When I update the grid (ajax) the data in the textbox is lost and so a null value is passed to the controller.

Is there anything I can do to ensure that when my scipt populates the text box the value is passed and not lost?

The javascript code is (this gets the value from a KendoDropDownBox using the on change event)

```
function pptLocationChange() {

    var ddl_text = $("#prompt_location").data("kendoDropDownList").text(),

        hidden_input = document.getElementById("ppt_location_name");
    hidden_input.value = ddl_text;
}
```

It puts the value of the drop down inside the ppt_location_name text box.  That all works fine, when I click on "Update" though a null value is passed to the controller despite me physically being able to see a value in it.

The Update code (omitted)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult vessels_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, tbl_vessels tbl_vessels, string ppt_location_name)
```

string ppt_location_name is the expected string value from the textbox but comes through as null since it's lost.

Is there anyway to "commit" this value when it's posted?

Many thanks

Comment: If this value is not part of the grid model are you actually passing this value back to the controller? from the sounds of it you are not. If this is part of the "edit" flow then why not include the text object as a model property.

Comment: This particular textbox is not bound to the model because we carry out extra functions once the value is passed.  If I don't populate the textbox with javascript adn type it in....it works.  That's not a scenario I can have though.

Comment: Why not create an `empty` property within the model and then do something like: <input type="textbox" data-bind="value:myModelValue"/> then you can do what ever you need to do with the drop down per your javascript function and then it will be returned as part of the model

Answer (score 0):

To make this work I added a KendoDropDownBox to my Editor Template.  Created an empty property in my model and bound the dropdown list to that.  This means that the dropdown value is properly passed to the controller and I can use it in my code without any problems.

So in a nutshell, create an empty property and reference it got the value to pass correctly.

Thanks @David Shorthose